# How to use the paypal payout api return url?

Tags: paypal, payout

I want to use the payout interface of paypal. Using curl in sandbox mode has been called. However, I dont know how to use returnUrl, because I need to know whether the payment of paypal is successful. This should be an asynchronous operation. I filled in the callback address in the location shown in the figure, but I checked the access log and found that no callback was received. Who can help me and how to solve this problem?

Comment: Please provide more details about your implementation and request.  The Payouts API reference does not specify anything about a callback: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.payouts-batch/v1/

Comment: on https://developer.paypal.com/ : DASHBOARD -- My Apps & Credentials -- REST API apps -- I created App name view details -- SANDBOX APP SETTINGS -- Return URL
“Users are redirected to this URL after live transactions. Allow up to three hours for the change to take effect. ” I thought it's a call back url setting, Paypal will call this url to update transaction status. If it not a call back url, how to let Paypal update status.

Answer (score 1):

The URL you speak of in REST App settings really only applies to things like Connect with PayPal or OpenID integrations, and has nothing to do with Payouts.

To be notified of Payouts status, see the API response of your Payouts request, or register for Webhook events that have to do with Payouts.

Comment: Could u please talk about the “Webhook” how to use  in detail ?
Does the "webhook" update the payment status asynchronously? when the transaction complete or failed?

Comment: Webhooks are asynchronous, yes, and documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/webhooks/

Comment: When I save Webhook URL，the page tips “Something went wrong during your request. Try again.”，Does the paypal sandbox stop service? https://www.paypal-status.com/product/sandbox

Comment: Should I go to some place to grant permission?
The save button do a request to https://developer.paypal.com/developer/webhooks/createwebhook , and this url response is "You do not have permission to view this page."

Comment: You can register for webhooks with an API call and not use that UI